# Linux CSV Remove Duplicate based on old date in big File (More than 100k Records)

Tags: linux, sorting, csv

We have the Following CSV file which contain

```
DCR_Path,Direction for Translation,Date & Time

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:22

data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:21

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:23

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2013 03:24

data3,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:10

data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:22

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:20
```

I need to take the latest and remove the other duplicates and output should be:

```
DCR_Path,Direction for Translation,Date & Time

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:23

data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:22

data3,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:10
```

I tried Below command but it is not deleting the data based on old date properly for huge records

```
awk -F ',' '{ if (Z) { "(date --date=\""$3"\" +\"%s\")" | getline X ; if (Y[$1] < X) {     Y[$1] = X; C[$1] = $0 } } else { Z = $0 } } END { print Z ; for (V in C) { print C[V] } }' < _YOUR_FILE_
```

It is throwing the below exception

```
awk: (FILENAME=merged-2014-11-12.csv FNR=145116) fatal: cannot open pipe `(date --date="Nov 6 2014 02:53 " +"%s")' (Too many open files)
```

Below is the location of the file which I am using..

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-v5SOZ1TWo-TEFGV05ZZFFwcXM/view?usp=sharing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to hit some kind of limit for open file descriptors, due to the huge number of `date` subprocesses. Perl seems to be a better candidate, it can do everything in one process.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nl
if ($. == 1) { print; next }
my ($key, $action, $date) = split /,/;
my ($mo, $d, $y, $h, $m) = split / |:/, $date;
$mo = {Jan=>0,Feb=>1,Mar=>2,Apr=>3,May=>4,Jun=>5,Jul=>6,Aug=>7,Sep=>8,Oct=>9,Nov=>10,Dec=>11}->{$mo};
my $m_cmp = $m + 60*$h + 24*60*$d + 31*24*60*$mo + 12*31*24*60*$y;
$dcr{$key} = [ $action, $date, $m_cmp ] if !$dcr{$key} || $m_cmp > $dcr{$key}->[2];
END {
    print join(",", $_, @{$dcr{$_}}[0,1] ) foreach (sort keys %dcr);
}
```

Comment: HI SZG where I need to specify the File Input and processed file output in the above script?

Comment: HI SZG pls ignore my previous question I got how to give input and output in perl and I am testing with the above command and share my outputs.

Comment: HI SZG the above solution worked perfect and thanks for your many more thanks for your help.

Comment: I hope it's still somewhat readable... What about an upvote? :-)